# Using @Query witouht extends from JpaRepository

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to execute system request using @Query. So, I do not have to extends JpaRepository and create an entity for no purpose.

I get this error:

```
Field myDAO in myPackage.impl.MyService required a bean of type 'myPackage.dao.MyDAO' that could not be found.
```

At MyService, I autowired MyDAO.

```
public class MyService implements IMyService {
    @Autowired
    private MyDAO myDAO;
    @Override
    public List<String> getAllTablesName() {
    return  myDAO.getAllTablesName();
    }
}
```

I try to add @Repository but nothing is changed

```
@Repository
public interface MyService{

    @Query(value ="SHOW TABLES FROM :tableName",nativeQuery = true)
    public List<String> getAllTablesName(@Param("tableName") String tableName);
}
```

How can I solve this problem ?

Comment: I'm not completely sure about the 'SHOW' command (and if it will work at all via JDBC) but a bind variable as table most certainly won't work.

Answer (score 0):

While you do not have to extend `JpaRepository` you'll at least have to extend `Repository`

If you really don't have an entity you probably shouldn't use JPA in the first place which is all about mapping entities to database tables.

If you just want to execute statements a better fit might be a simple class with an injected `JdbcTemplate` or `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate`.

Comment: `JdbcTemplate`  or `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate` need a `ResultSetExtractor` to map the result of the query. It's the same issue. I cannot use `@Repository` and add the package name to the `@EnableJpaRepositories`. It doesn't recognize the dao as a bean

Comment: You don't need a `ResultSetExtractor` you can use methods like `queryForList(java.lang.String sql, java.lang.Class<T> elementType)`. I don't understand the second sentence: The resulting bean isn't a Spring Data Repository. You need to extend `Repository` for that which requires you to have an entity which you don't seem to want.